# html:Button thats supposed to do create a rectangle does nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Yes, I asked a similar question already, but I have to ask it again, 'cause I'm a slow learner.:(
So the good thing is: I don't get 'a few(read:"a lot")' of Errors raining down at me.
The bad thing is: I don't get anything...
The button just does nothing!
It's supposed to modify the size of a rectangle!
I tried to make it execute this function:

```
function a(){
class Rectangle{
  constructor(height, width){
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

  function createRectangle(height, width){
    var input1 = document.getElementbyId("1stinput").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementbyId("2ndinput").value;
    var input1int = parseFloat(input1);
    var input2int = parseFloat(input2);
    const Rectangle1 = Rectangle(width="${input1int}",height="${input2int}");
    document.querySelector("#svg").setAttribute("width", parseFloat(Rectangle1.width));
    document.querySelector("#svg").setAttribute("height", parseFloat(Rectangle1.height));
};};};};
```

Those are the input fields for the size:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="" id="1stinput">
<input type="text" name="" value="" id="2ndinput">
```

And this is the rectangle:

```
<svg width=0 height=0 id="svg">
  <rect width=0 height=0 style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" id="Rectangle"/>
</svg>
```

Alright could someone please help me,I don't know what to do here,thanks for all the help!
Bye!

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do here. Your class constructor is trying to create an instance of itself? But then it simply changes the pre-existing SVG's dimensions so that it becomes visible? Also, it's `.getElementById()`, not `.getElementbyId()`. It doesn't seem like you need a class at all here - - just alter the size of the SVG.

Comment: Also, where is your `button` that is supposed to create the rectangle that you say does nothing?

Comment: @Scott Marcus this is the button: `<button id = "button1">create</button>`    `const button1 = document.querySelector("#button1")
    button1.addEventListener("click", a(), false);`

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough rep to make comments, so this answer may be a bit of back and fourth.

I am not sure how you are executing your script, but I see a problem with closure. The constructor has no closure which will throw errors after instantiating the `Rectangle` class.

In order to help more I need to know how you are calling function `a` and instantiating the `Rectangle` class. As of now I see nothing instantiating the class nor how the `createRectangle` method within is being called. The `createRectangle` method will throw an error if called as it is now, as the `function` syntax is not valid syntax for defining methods.

For example this script throws and error:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    function getFoo(){
        return this.foo;
    }
}

const test = new Foo("bar");

console.log(test.getFoo())
```

This script with correct syntax does not throw errors:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    getFoo(){
        return this.foo;
    }
}

const test = new Foo("bar");
console.log(test.getFoo());
```

Comment: Answers should not be "back and forth" discussions. Work on providing good quality answers so that  you get enough rep to be able to comment.

Comment: @ScottMarcus How are we to gain reputation to ASK or comment if we need 50 rep to ask questions to begin with. It is hard to find questions that are written well enough that someone does not need to write an answer that assumes what the OP is attempting to do. It is rules like this and people like you that make SO so toxic. OP even has a -1 for asking the question. They are clearly new and inexperience so I have two options, ask questions and help them learn or hand them an answer on a silver platter.

Comment: There is nothing toxic about having a platform that has rules for participating in it. As someone who has been a member for over a decade and cares a lot about helping people, I can say that what makes SO toxic is all the new users who don't bother to learn about what SO is and how to use it. It's not as hard as you think to focus in on an area you have good knowledge in and write good answers to build up your rep.

Comment: I am also well aware of SO rules and have been a user (non registered) for over a decade as well and have seen many a person on other sites comment that it is hard to get started. I have another account that is over 5 years old where I had the same issue.

Comment: If you are well aware of SO rules and have been a member for several years and are still posting "answers" that go against the rules, then I would say you may be aware of them, but you aren't following them. That's on you, not us.

Comment: I keep trying and still have the same problems, when I assume what the OP wants and hand out answers I never get an upvote because they come back and say "That wasn't what I was trying to do" See the only other post I ever made with this account as an example..

Comment: In the case of this answer, why not take the advice that you currently have and rework the OP's code so that it works, making sure to explain the changes that you've made and why they are necessary? That would be a good answer.

Comment: @radiantPudding: Please note that you need 50 rep to leave comments (outside of your own posts). You do _not_ need 50 rep to ask questions, as you noted above. As far as assuming what people want only to find out that it's not: Ideally, if questions are ambiguous, they should be flagged as requiring more detail (though that may require a bit of rep, too). Many questions posted here are not well-formed and cannot be answered without further detail; we strive to close them. It's useful to avoid answering those until they've been updated with additional information.